# Python Pandas: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

i'm currently trying to merge a shapefile with a csv. Unfortunately, my code won't work, as i get the following error:

```
---> 17 merged = gdf.merge(df, left_on = 'ID', right_on = 'ID')
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

My code is as follows:

```
shapefile ='C:/Users/User/Desktop/Shapefile/Stadtteil.shp'

gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile)[['ID2', 'ID2FLOAT' , 'Shape_Leng' , 'Shape_Area']]

gdf.columns = [['ID','IDFLOAT','Shape_Leng' , 'Shape_Area']]

gdf.head()

import pandas as pd

datafile = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Stadtteile3.csv' 

df = pd.read_csv(datafile, names = ['ID','Einwohner'], skiprows = 1) 
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
df.head()

merged = gdf.merge(df, left_on = 'ID', right_on = 'ID')


#---------------------------------------------------------
# I also tried the following:

#df['ID']=df['ID'].astype(int)
#gdf = gdf.astype(int)
#gdf['ID']=gdf['ID'].astype(int)

#import numpy as np
#x=np.concatenate(gdf['ID'],df['ID'])
#---------------------------------------------------------
```

The datafiles are as follows:

[image: Screenshot of Excel]
[image: Screenshot of SHP]

Thank you so much!

Comment: In your pic, it's written "ID2" not "ID" and in your code you're trying to merge "ID" on "ID" :)